# How can I do a regex pattern for Hibernate validation?

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I want to use a regex `@Pattern` with `Hibernate` validation. How can I do this regex expression?

[a][b][c][d][e] is a number with 13 digits like this: 1831222132132

```
a - one digit, 1 or 2, nothing else;
b - from 01 to 99, it is the last 2 digits from the year, for ex 1983 => b = 83;
c - from 01 to 12;
d - from 01 to 31;
e - 6 digits;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To validate that in Hibernate you can use `@Pattern` annotation like this

```
@Column(name = "myInpt")
@Pattern(regexp = "^[12](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([0-9]{6})$", message = "Incorrect format")
private String myInput;
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how can I do to show the error message in the response body? Now the message is empty {
    "timestamp": "2020-06-03T17:20:20.721+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/ibantoiban"
}

Comment: In your controller, you should use @valid annotation. Also, you make sure you do not overwrite the default behavior of exception handling in your code.
code example:

Comment: @PostMapping("/zzz")
 public ResponseEntity<ZZZ> addzzz(@Valid @RequestBody ZZZ zzz)